# fontawesome css is not included by gruntfile

Tags: css, gruntjs, font-awesome, jhipster

I am running version 2.22.0 of jhipster app. Recently I installed font awesome using bower including it in bower.json file. The problem is that after running grunt serve any css files of font awesome is included in index.html. I've read a closed issue (#748) but nothing.

Finally I added this in overrides section of bower.json, like it is done with bootstrap files, and now font-awesome.css is included in idex.html.

```
"overrides": {
    ....
    "fontawesome": {
        "main": [
            "css/font-awesome.css",
            "scss/font-awesome.scss",
            "less/font-awesome.less"
        ]
    }
 }
```

Is this the right solution? And is this required for every external js/css file?

P.D. I have read the documentation of hjipster and I don't see nothing about this solution in "Using JHipster in development"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is a way of doing when not using sass, with sass it's much simpler as you would just import font-awesome.scss in your main.scss file.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the "-" in "font-awesome". It worked then! Thanks!